# Can I define different case rules for different type of variables in Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I want to have different case for boolean variables and integer variables.
eg - bool UPPERCASE;
    int camelCase;
How to define rule in resharper to check for that?

Comment: I must say; the resharper naming conventions are pretty good. You could try to convince yourself to use them ;-)

Comment: This link is for you:https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html

Comment: This isn't possible with Resharper as you can't set a style per type. You could write a Roslyn analyzer, but why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: yes, but roslyn does not support vs2013

Comment: There is a reason why MS recommends certain ways of casing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions